# Bizarre genius detective

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> My first could be short for a well-meaning tyrant.
>   The start of my last ends a widely-used food plant.
>   Its end can be cookies or data migration.
>   My talk with poor Yorick caused quite a sensation.

Who am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This role may be played by:

> Benedict Cumberbatch

My first could be short for a well-meaning tyrant.

> Bene-dict being short for a benevolent dictator.

The start of my last ends a widely-used food plant.

> Cu**cumber**

Its end can be cookies or data migration.

> A batch of cookies or server-to-server data transfer.

My talk with poor Yorick caused quite a sensation.

> He's played Hamlet who talks to Yorick's skull.

Title: Bizarre genious detective

> Cumberbatch has also played Doctor Strange, Alan Turing and Sherlock Holmes.

Comment: All correct. Nice work!